# What does sysprep with the generalize option do on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cloning, sysprep

I want to create a template of Windows Server 2008 R2 for virtualization. Therefore I use the sysprep tool by Microsoft. This works fine. I just wonder what the generalize option is good for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The sysprep /generalize command removes unique information from your Windows installation, which enables you to reuse that image on different computers.  You should CHECK GENERALIZE FOR SURE or you'll have duplicate SIDs on your network.

Comment: Failing to do this caused issues at my job as msdtc generates a guid on installation and it doesn't like when two servers are using the same value.